# Filter and sort based on attributes in Terms lookup document in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents in my index:

```
POST "/index/thing/_bulk" -s -d'
    { "index":{ "_id": 1 } }
    { "title":"One thing"}
    { "index":{ "_id": 2 } }
    { "title":"Second thing"}
    { "index":{ "_id": 3 } }
    { "title":"Three things"}
    { "index":{ "_id": 4 } }
    { "title":"And so fourth"}
    { "index":{ "_id": 5 } }
    { "title":"Five things"}
'
```

I also have documents which contain a users `collection` which are linked to the other documents (things) through the documents `id` attribute like so:

```
PUT /index/collection/1
{
    "items": [
        {"id": 1, "time_added": "2017-08-07T09:07:15.000Z", "condition": "fair"},
        {"id": 3, "time_added": "2019-08-07T09:07:15.000Z", "condition": "good"},
        {"id": 4, "time_added": "2016-08-07T09:07:15.000Z", "condition": "poor"}
    ]
}
```

I then use a [terms lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup) to get all the things in a users collection like so:

```
GET /documents/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "_id" : {
                "index" : "index",
                "type" : "collection",
                "id" : 1,
                "path" : "items.id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. I get the three documents in the collection and can search, sort and use aggregations like I want.

But is there a way to aggregate, filter and sort those documents based on the attributes (`time_added` or `condition` in this case) in the `collection` document? Say I wanted to sort based on `time_added` or filter for `condition=="good"` from the collection?

Maybe a script that can be applied to `collection` to sort or filter the items in there? It feels like this is getting pretty close to sql like left-join, so maybe Elastic Search is the wrong tool?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the [nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

Taking your data as an example:

**Without nested type**:

```
POST collection/_bulk?filter_path=_
{"index":{}}
{"items":[{"id":11,"time_added":"2017-08-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"fair"},{"id":13,"time_added":"2019-08-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"good"},{"id":14,"time_added":"2016-08-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"poor"}]}
{"index":{}}
{"items":[{"id":21,"time_added":"2017-09-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"fair"},{"id":23,"time_added":"2019-09-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"good"},{"id":24,"time_added":"2016-09-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"poor"}]}
{"index":{}}
{"items":[{"id":31,"time_added":"2017-10-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"fair"},{"id":33,"time_added":"2019-10-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"good"},{"id":34,"time_added":"2016-10-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"poor"}]}
{"index":{}}
{"items":[{"id":41,"time_added":"2017-11-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"fair"},{"id":43,"time_added":"2019-11-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"good"},{"id":44,"time_added":"2016-11-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"poor"}]}
{"index":{}}
{"items":[{"id":51,"time_added":"2017-12-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"fair"},{"id":53,"time_added":"2019-12-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"good"},{"id":54,"time_added":"2016-12-07T09:07:15.000Z","condition":"poor"}]}
```

Query (you'd get incorrect results - expected one, got five):

```
GET collection/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "items.condition": {
              "value": "good"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "items.time_added": {
              "lte": "2019-09-01"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Aggregation (incorect results - look at the first bucket `"2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"` - it contains 3 `CONDITION` sub-buckets with every condition type)

```
GET collection/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "DATE": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "items.time_added",
        "calendar_interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "CONDITION": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "items.condition.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**With nested type**

```
DELETE collection

PUT collection
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "items": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

# and POST the same data from above
```

Query (returns just one result)

```
GET collection/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "items",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "items.condition": {
                  "value": "good"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "items.time_added": {
                  "lte": "2019-09-01"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Aggregation (the first date bucket contains just one `CONDITION` sub-bucket)

```
GET collection/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ITEMS": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "items"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "DATE": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "items.time_added",
            "calendar_interval": "month"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "CONDITION": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "items.condition.keyword",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I imagine I'd have to index the collection array as nested, but how would I then make queries based on them?

Comment: [ES guides](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) describes it pretty well. I added an example based on your data above.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration @jetnet. I'm afraid it doesn't fully answer my questions,  I think maybe it wasn't clear enough, I've added more detail. I don't want to search on the collection, but rather use it to filter through other documents and wondering if I can do that and still use attributes from to sort or filter.